# Align Button in the Vertical Center and Keep it Stationary in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I currently have a bootstrap button that is vertically aligned in a column on the left of the screen. I am using the following code:

```
        <div class="col-sm-1 align-self-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
```

It looks exactly how I want it to on the page, but I recently noticed that as other modules expand the page downward (I have a collapsable panel in another column), this button shifts down as well. I suspect it continues to align itself with the center of the page as the page's height changes.

My question is whether there was a way to vertically align the button in the center as I currently do but also have it remain stationary should the length of the page change. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post *all* relevant code

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue requires using a wrapper around the element to give it a static reference in terms of its vertical center.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper a {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div id="wrapper" class="row">
    <a class="btn my-auto">Hello!</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>
      This is another row, but the one above is centered within the wrapper above.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never place content directly in `row`. Only `col-*` should be the direct children of `row`